# How to design a database model for a large data warehouse?

Tags: data-modeling, data-warehouse, datamodel

Lets say I design a database model for an online seller such as Amazon:

[image]

Next, to create the database model for the larger data warehouse, I flatten the Order and OrderDetails tables, and flatten the Product and Vendor tables:

[image]

I do this to apply the concept of designing models for parent-child applications, as described here http://bit.ly/1bOuOXQ

The data in the data warehouse tables becomes repetitive:

[image]

Several values such as $76.30 for OrderTotal repeat on each row, is this correct?  Is the model correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each row represents a match for each product, the corresponding order subtotal and total will be identical for each row with a specific orderid.

The result is as expected for your model definition.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

OrderTotal is the same for all records, so it is duplicated when you put everything in a single spreadsheet.

(Of course, in a relational database you are keep data in several tables, so it isn't duplicated.)

Comment: Agreed. The oddity isn't the data, but the way you've chosen to format the data.

Comment: If there's something in particular you're concerned about, ask the question. If you're looking for general code/design review, you're on the wrong Stack Exchange board.

Comment: @keshlam, I think he was wondering about the duplicity of OrderTotal.

Comment: @Paul, We've already answered that one, I think, so I read this as a more general "anything else"... judgement call but I think that's getting into the CodeReview area rather than StackOverflow.